# Getting the NullPointerException when I run this code

Tags: grails, groovy, nullpointerexception

I have a `User` class like this:

```
package com.grailsinaction

class User {
    String userId
    String password;
    Date dateCreated
    Profile profile
    static hasMany = [posts : Post]
        static constraints = {
        userId(size:3..20, unique:true)
        password(size:6..8, validator : { passwd,user ->
                            passwd!=user.userId
                        })
        dateCreated()
        profile(nullable:true)
        }
    static mapping = {
        profile lazy:false
    }
}
```

`Post` class like this:

```
package com.grailsinaction

class Post {
    String content
    Date dateCreated;
    static constraints = {
    content(blank:false)
    }
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}
```

And I write an integration test like this:

```
//other code goes here
void testAccessingPost() {
        def user = new User(userId:'anto',password:'adsds').save()
        user.addToPosts(new Post(content:"First"))
        def foundUser = User.get(user.id)
        def postname = foundUser.posts.collect { it.content }
        assertEquals(['First'], postname.sort())
    }
```

And I run using `grails test-app -integration`, then I get a error like this :

```
Cannot invoke method addToPosts() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method addToPosts() on null object
    at com.grailsinaction.PostIntegrationTests.testAccessingPost(PostIntegrationTests.groovy:23
```

Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `save()` method is returning null. Try this instead:

```
def user = new User(userId:'anto',password:'adsds')
user.save() // Do you even need this?
user.addToPosts(new Post(content:"First"))
```

According to [the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html):

> The save method returns null if validation failed and the instance was not saved and the instance itself if successful.

So it's possible that you should be looking at what's going wrong in validation... do you need to specify that some of the fields are optional, for example? (I'm not a Grails developer - just trying to give you some ideas.)

Comment: Not A Grails Developer But An C# Developer ;) ;) this works, I made a mistake and violated the validation :D Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Ant's it *is* possible to know more than one technology

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix: your password has to be between 6 to 8 characters (check your constraints field).

A stupid idea, at best, to have a maximum size for a password (eventually they should be hashed and will bear no resemblance to the original password).

On a side note, may I suggest The Definitive Guide to Grails instead?